# How to create a list menu in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I would like to create a simple 4-item list menu as a main menu for an application. My first thought is to create a ListView but I know that ListView objects use an adapter to display their items. I don't want to use an adapter as there is no data to display, just new activities, which the list options lead to. What are the alternatives available to tackle this problem?

Comment: Your data for the adapter is the list of activities.

Comment: That is true, but I was thinking of a simpler solution. I'm thinking of implementing a LinearLayout to "emulate" the list form with clickable TextViews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to go about it. You could build a list with objects to create your own menu.

> I don't want to use an adapter as there is no data to display, just new activities, which the list options lead to.

I think you are misunderstanding something. Every class in java extends `Object`. So you could have a list of activities and by clicking on that item you could start the activity. [Here is a good tutorial](https://www.thenewboston.com/index.php) where he is doing exactly that (videos 18 - 21) *Hosted by [TheNewBoston](https://www.thenewboston.com/index.php), and made by [MyBringBack](http://www.mybringback.com/)*

It is not wrong to go about it the way you originally thought, but for ease of use, design, and consistency, I suggest implementing one of Android's menus:

- [Navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
- Options menu
- Action bar menu
- Context menu
- Popup menu.

Last few can be [found here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I phrased my question as well as I should. I'm trying to emulate the following:

https://jkontherun.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/wave_secure_3a_main_menu.png

Formatting (images, color) aside, what is the best way to achieve this? The options menu is not really suitable for this and the ListAdapter expects a Cursor as data source. How would I "feed" the adapter the list item activities?

Comment: I would use an ArrayAdapter for this. Vogella does a very intuitive tutorial on this. Will even show you how to add the icons and color if you want -- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Yeap, definitely see the logic behind your choice in this. Many thanks for the link too.